# "Прям" — это вводное слово?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Пожалуйста, ответьте, является ли в данном случае слово "прям" вводным? И стоит ли его выделять запятыми?
"...Маргарет, прям, в плач..."

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна. *Прямо* - частица, вводным словом не бывает.

Answer (score 2):

**Прям**, частица; *прост.* употребляется при выражении усиления значения; соответствует по значению словам *совершенно, просто.*
Выделения запятыми не требует, вводным словом не является.

**...Маргарет прям в плач...**

*И даже не то чтобы рассказывает – а **прям-таки** плачет.*
А. Максимов. Так любят люди

*У него **прям** руки чесались, чтобы сделать что-нибудь приятное, он представил, что пришёл с коробкой конфет и цветами.*
О. Пензина. Больше не друзья